# Can i stop rendering while i'm rendering in a video format

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine

I am rendering one file of 200 frame it's been an hour an it is 30 frames. I am rendering it in a FFmpeg Video format. Can i stop rendering it but also it should be playable? Can someone tell me how can i stop it but by making the video playable. i am rendering it in a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

No. When rendering straight to video you cannot pause the render.

Most people render out as a png sequence (which can be paused) then convert it to a video afterwards.

See the following blog for a more in depth explanation of the process and why we do it this way: https://www.graphicsandprogramming.net/eng/tutorial/blender/the-video-sequence-editor/blender-convert-sequence-images-mp4

Edit: The English isn’t perfect but it should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

you can not pause to preview but you can press Escape to stop rendering, and the video will be perfectly playable... eventually render a second video and join, or change some settings to improve render times and start from the beginning

if you go the image sequence way -as Onyx suggested- a nice little option is to disable in Output Properties > Output > Image Sequence > Overlay... so you can stop any time, play your rendered frames and resume rendering -it will skip already rendered frames-